# Why am I getting this error when trying to implement Google Play in app review

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am trying to implement google in app review. I have followed the documentation here

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/unity

I am only using the code they provided for now but as soon as i call new ReviewManager() i get this error

Exception: Field currentActivity or type signature  not found
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/AndroidJNI/AndroidJava.cs:1446)

I have been looking for hours but can not find any information on this. Can someone please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you should try to:
1.if you have a device simulator, switch it off

''Had a similar issue, and after my head went all bold, I noticed that I didn't get this
problem when I switch off the device simulator!!!''

2. You need to install the Android module for 2019.2.17 in Unity Hub, every time you change version you need to install Android for that version.

3.try to just test the Google sign in the actual app and not in the editor if you are running it on there

Comment: do not have a device simulator, The android module is installed, and I'v tested on the phone.

Comment: this is an existing app on the store. Everything works fine, except for this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review try this